# Nextjs/Reactjs: How to route to different pages within sidebar component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My app.js:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
       <ThemeProvider attribute="class">
           <Context>
               <Sidebar>
                   <Component>
                     {pageProps}
                   </Component>
               </Sidebar>
           </Context>
       </ThemeProvider>
  )
};
```

so the only way I have been able get my home page show up is by importing it into my sidebar and rendering it directly like the following:

```
import Home from "../home";

export default function Sidebar() {
// Do Something
}

return (
  <>
    <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
      <Home/>
    </div>
  </>
```

The issue I am having is that when I sign in on my homepage it's suppose to route to another page when I click a specific button, and even though the link is actually changing the rendering isn't changing and is still only showing my  page but not my  page.

I know it's because I have  in the return of function Sidebar(){}, but how do I get it to not only render my Home page but to also render my Dashboard page after I click the button that is suppose to route it. When I don't use the sideboard component everything routes fine when I click the buttons that do the routing, but when I add in the sidebar component I the buttons only change the link changes from "./home" to "./dashboard", but the  page is still rendered and not the  page (the one I want rendered after the button is clicked).

Edit:

home.js

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import {getAuth} from "./services/auth"
import { app } from "./services/server";

export default function Home() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { user, setUser }  = useState()
    const { auth } = getAuth(app)

    async function button(){
        try {

            const res = await signIn(auth);
            setUser(res.credentials.user.uid)
            console.log(res.credentials.user.displayName)

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      if (user) router.replace("/dashboard");
    }, [user]);

    return (
      <div className="">
          <div className="">
              <div className="">
                  <button
                      className=""
                      onClick={button}
                  >
                      Enter
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, why did you put your home page in the sidebar component to get it to show up? why not put it in the index.js file so that it will be rendered as the path "/"?
Also, you're doing router.replace instead of using router.push, so your are changing the url but not routing to it.
My advice, move your home component to index.js so it will be rendered as your home page, and
if you have a dashboard page with path "/dashboard", use:

`router.push("/dashboard")` instead of `router.replace`

or use Link from `next/link` instead of the button tag like this:

```
<Link href="/dashboard">
<a>
Enter
</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: The reason I put the home there in my sidebar is to render it, because when I don't have it there it doesn't render even while I have my home component in my index.js. I found a workaround by creating an AppContainer component and having that replace in the sidebar component instead of my home page, and then I use an inline if-else conditional operator but this only works when I am going to one of 2 pages depeneding on state. The workaround doesn't help when I have more than 2 pages I want to navigate to from the homepage while keeping the sidebar intact between the pages.

Comment: I think the problem here is why your component doesn't render if you put it in index.js. Please comment out the useEffect and put your component in index.js and see if it's rendered or not.
Also your work around isn't routing between pages, it's just conditional rendering between 2 components.
Try to use the router.push method instead of replace

Comment: You cannot use <a> inside a Link.

Comment: @ytpm I think this was before Nextjs v13, where we had to use <a> inside the <Link>